# Distribution of a certain functional of iid $N(0,1)$ random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid $N(0,1)$ random variables. Consider the random variable given by
> $$
> \xi_n
> =\Bigl|\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t\Bigr|^2-\frac1n\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2
> =\frac1n\sum_{s\ne t}X_sX_t.
> $$
> What is the distribution of $\xi_n$?

My observations are as follow.

1. We have that $n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t\sim N(0,1)$ and $|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t|^2\sim\chi^2(1)$, where $\chi^2(k)$ is the chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom.
2. $\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2\sim\chi^2(n)$ and $n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2\sim\Gamma(k=n/2,\theta = 2n^{-1})$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Related_distributions)).
3. $|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t|^2$ and $n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2$ are not independent since the covariance between them is equal to $2/n$ (although the covariance goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$).
4. $n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2\to 1$ in probability as $n\to\infty$ using the law of large numbers and hence it follows that $\xi_n\to \chi^2(1)-1$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$ using Slutsky's theorem. However, I am interested if the exact distribution has some manageable form when $n$ is some fixed positive integer.

If $|n^{-1/2}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t|^2$ and $n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2$ were independent, then we could try to use the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48378/46220) to derive the exact distribution. But they are not independent. Maybe [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem) might be of use here.

Does the exact distribution of $\xi_n$ have some manageable expression?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: for large $n$ the distribution of $\xi_n$ is a Gaussian of zero mean and unit variance; I would think that this limit is reached quickly, with corrections of order $1/n$; for example, the exact result for the variance is ${\rm var}\,\xi_n=1-1/n$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I think $\xi_n$ converges in distribution to $\chi^2(1)-1$. It follows from the standard CLT and the continuous mapping theorem that the first term converges to $\chi^2(1)$ in distribution and the second term converges to $1$ in probability as $n\to\infty$ (I am referring to the expression in the middle). Then we conclude using Slutsky's theorem. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: One can make this independent by diagonalizing the symmetric matrix. Let $Y_i = ( \sum_{j=1}^i X_j   -  i.X_{i+1} )/ \sqrt{ i (i+1)}$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$ and let $Y_n = (\sum_{j=1}^n X_j ) / \sqrt{n}$. Then $Y_i, Y_{n}$ are also independent Gaussians with mean $0$ and variance $1$ if I calculated correctly, and $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$ so you can express your sum as $Y_n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 /n$ and thus as a difference of two chi-squared variables.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks a lot for your comment! Which matrix do we diagonalize here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X_1,\dots, X_n$ Gaussian random variables with variance-covariance matrix $M$, and $L$ a $m \times n$ matrix, the variables $Y_1,\dots, Y_m$ given by $Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n L_{ij} X_j$ have variance-covariance matrix $L M L^T$.

This follows immediately from writing the covariance as an expectation of products of sums, exchanging the sum and product, and then exchanging the sum and expectation.

In particular, if $M$ is the identity matrix, and $L$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix, then the $Y_i$ have variance-covariance matrix the identity, hence are independent standard Gaussians (because Gaussians are determined by their variance-covariance matrix (and mean, which is zero throughout this discussion and hence can be ignored)).

Given any quadratic function $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij} X_i X_j$ of the $n$ Gaussian random variables, determined by a matrix $C$, which without loss of generality we can assume is symmetric, we can understand the distribution of $C$ by changing variables from the $X_i$ to the $Y_i$. This has the effect of sending $C$ to $ L^{-1} C L^{-T}$, which if $L$ is orthogonal is $L^T C L$.

Since every symmetric matrix can be diagonalized, we can make $C$ a diagonal matrix by this approach.

In your case $C$ is the matrix with off-diagonal entries $\frac{1}{n}$ and diagonal entries $0$. By viewing this as the all-$\frac{1}{n}$s matrix minus a diaogonal matrix, we see it has eigenvalues $\frac{n-1}{n}, \frac{-1}{n},\dots, \frac{-1}{n}$, and thus diagonalizing it turns it into a diagonal matrix with entries $\frac{n-1}{n}, \frac{-1}{n},\dots, \frac{-1}{n}$.

To be explicit we can find a specific orthonormal basis on which the matrix diagoanlizes, of which one vector must be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\dots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and the rest can be any orthonormal basis orthogonal to it - one of which I wrote down in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

One has
$$\xi_n=(n-1)\bar X^2-\frac{n-1}n\,S^2=U+V,$$
where
$$\bar X:=\frac1n\,\sum_1^n X_i,\quad S^2:=\frac1{n-1}\,\sum_1^n(X_i-\bar X)^2
=\frac1{n-1}\Big(\sum_1^n X_i^2-n\bar X^2\Big),$$
$$U:=\frac{n-1}n Z^2,\quad Z:=\bar X\sqrt n,\quad V:=-\frac1n\,\chi_{n-1}^2,\quad
\chi_{n-1}^2:=(n-1)S^2.$$
Further, $Z\sim N(0,1)$, $\chi_{n-1}^2=(n-1)S^2$ has the chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, and $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are independent. So, $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables with easily found pdf's, and the pdf of $\xi_n$ is the convolution of the pdf's of $U$ and $V$.